# Alignment of radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I would like the radio buttons to appear to the left of the labels as opposed to above.  Help much appreciated.  Thanks.

Using WordPress plugin cForm builder.

http://www.alagroup.com.au/whiteowlmumsanddads/

```
  <div class="wdform_row" style="opacity: 1;" wdid="26">
           <div id="wdform_field26" type="type_radio" class="wdform_field" style="display: table-cell;">
                <div align="left" id="26_label_sectionform_id_temp" class="" style="display: block; width: 480px;">
                     <span id="26_element_labelform_id_temp" class="label" style="vertical-align: top;">
                          Is there something in particular you are interested in? 
                     </span>
                     <span id="26_required_elementform_id_temp" class="required" style="vertical-align: middle;">
                     </span>
                </div>
                <div align="left" id="26_element_sectionform_id_temp" class="" style="display: table-cell;">
                     <input type="hidden" value="type_radio" name="26_typeform_id_temp" id="26_typeform_id_temp">
                     <input type="hidden" value="no" name="26_requiredform_id_temp" id="26_requiredform_id_temp">
                     <input type="hidden" value="no" name="26_randomizeform_id_temp" id="26_randomizeform_id_temp">
                     <input type="hidden" value="no" name="26_allow_otherform_id_temp" id="26_allow_otherform_id_temp">
                     <input type="hidden" value="0" name="26_allow_other_numform_id_temp" id="26_allow_other_numform_id_temp">
                     <input type="hidden" value="6" name="26_rowcol_numform_id_temp" id="26_rowcol_numform_id_temp">
                     <div style="display: table;">
                          <div id="26_table_little" style="display: table-row-group;" for_hor="26_hor">
                               <div id="26_element_tr0" style="display: block;">
                                    <div valign="top" id="26_td_little0" idi="0" style="display: table-cell;">
                                         <input type="radio" value="Life Insurance" id="26_elementform_id_temp0" name="26_elementform_id_temp" onclick="set_default(&quot;26&quot;,&quot;0&quot;,&quot;form_id_temp&quot;)" >
                                         <label id="26_label_element0" class="ch_rad_label" for="26_elementform_id_temp0">
                                              Life Insurance 
                                         </label>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id="26_element_tr1" style="display: block;">
                                    <div valign="top" id="26_td_little1" idi="1" style="display: table-cell;">
                                         <input type="radio" value="Income Protection" id="26_elementform_id_temp1" name="26_elementform_id_temp" onclick="set_default(&quot;26&quot;,&quot;1&quot;,&quot;form_id_temp&quot;)" >
                                         <label id="26_label_element1" class="ch_rad_label" for="26_elementform_id_temp1">
                                              Income Protection 
                                         </label>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id="26_element_tr2" style="display: table-row;">
                                    <div valign="top" id="26_td_little2" idi="2" style="display: table-cell;">
                                         <input type="radio" value="Trauma Insurance" id="26_elementform_id_temp2" name="26_elementform_id_temp" onclick="set_default(&quot;26&quot;,&quot;2&quot;,&quot;form_id_temp&quot;)" >
                                         <label id="26_label_element2" class="ch_rad_label" for="26_elementform_id_temp2">
                                              Trauma Insurance 
                                         </label>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id="26_element_tr3" style="display: table-row;">
                                    <div valign="top" id="26_td_little3" idi="3" style="display: table-cell;">
                                         <input type="radio" value="Business Insurance" id="26_elementform_id_temp3" name="26_elementform_id_temp" onclick="set_default(&quot;26&quot;,&quot;3&quot;,&quot;form_id_temp&quot;)" >
                                         <label id="26_label_element3" class="ch_rad_label" for="26_elementform_id_temp3">
                                              Business Insurance 
                                         </label>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id="26_element_tr4" style="display: table-row;">
                                    <div valign="top" id="26_td_little4" idi="4" style="display: table-cell;">
                                         <input type="radio" value="Other" id="26_elementform_id_temp4" name="26_elementform_id_temp" onclick="set_default(&quot;26&quot;,&quot;4&quot;,&quot;form_id_temp&quot;)" >
                                         <label id="26_label_element4" class="ch_rad_label" for="26_elementform_id_temp4">
                                              Other 
                                         </label>
                                    </div>
                               </div>
                               <div id="26_element_tr5" style="display: table-row;">
                               </div>
                          </div>
                     </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use some custom CSS to align the radio buttons with the label.

I've never used wordpress myself, but it looks like it is supported.

> Can I use Custom CSS to make minor visual changes to an existing
>   theme?
>   [Reference](https://en.support.wordpress.com/custom-design/custom-css/)

Copying your markup into JSFiddle gives me the result your looking for: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87wpt72z/). You haven't included any of the styling being applied to the page. Using Chrome dev tools (F12) on the [page](http://www.alagroup.com.au/whiteowlmumsanddads/) you linked to, i first tried applying the following styles:

```
div#wdform_field26 .input[type="radio"] {
    float: left;
}
```

However given the existing styling on the page, this didn't look quite right.
I would discourage using `float` as this removes the element from the regular hierarchy, making subsequent styling trickier.

[image: Using float:left]

I then applied the following styles and achieved the result i think your looking for:

```
div#wdform_field26 .input[type="radio"] {
  height: auto !important;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

div#wdform_field26 .label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[image: Using display:inline-block]

I would always recommend using `block` or `inline-block` display mode over `floats` as it makes subsequent styling more predictable, of-course both have their place.

While i simply applied the styles to the elements themselves i tried to provide example code with accurate selectors, you will need to double check this doesn't affect elements incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

use `float:left`

Please use float:left Css property to the Input radio button

```
    <input  type="radio" value="Life Insurance" 
name="26_element12contact"  style="float:left"/>
```